# request.fullpath with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

In my application controller, I have a couple of methods defined as follows:

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)

  # make sure this method doesn't redirect back to the current page
  if session[:return_to] == request.fullpath
    redirect_to default
  else
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  end

  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

In order to test these methods, I need to find some way to set `request.fullpath` in RSpec.  Does anybody know how I can accomplish this?

**Update**

When testing these methods, I'm using a shared example group, like so:

```
shared_examples_for "redirect back or default" do
  it "should redirect" do
    request
    response.should be_redirect
  end

  describe "when the user has a back page" do
    it "should redirect to back"
  end

  describe "when the user does not have a back page" do
    it "should redirect to default" do
      request
      response.should redirect_to(default_path)
    end
  end
end
```

When including the shared example groups, I do something like the following:

```
before(:each) do
  def request
    post :create, :user => @attr
  end
  def default_path
    :root
  end
end

include_examples "redirect back or default"
```

Thus, when a method use redirect_back_or_default, I just have to add the above code to its tests and I'm done.In this way, I can still be specific about testing `redirect_back_or_default` without having to test against the implementation, which seems like a better way to do BDD to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to a @request object that you might be able to set directly, like:

```
@request.fullpath = "/my/path"
```

My guess is that will be overridden when you make your actual get/post/put/delete, however, in the controller spec.

Any reason you want to set fullpath directly rather than knowing fullpath will just be something simple like "/mock"?

```
class MocksController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end

describe MocksController do
  before do
    MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
      resource :mock, :only => [:show]
    end
  end

  after do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end

  it "something" do
    get :show
    should # something
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't exactly understand what you're doing with the routes draw command at the top of your test.  Could you please explain that a little?

Comment: The routes stuff is necessary just to get a subclass of ApplicationController.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I'm being completely clear in my question.  I'll update it now.

Comment: Oh you don't need to draw the routes, rspec2 has some nicer stuff for that:
http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/dir/controller-specs/anonymous-controller